java.util.Date converted to LocalDate returns Strange results
    Date date = new Date();
    Calendar cal1 = Calendar.getInstance();

    cal1.set(Calendar.YEAR, 0001);
    cal1.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
    cal1.set(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.JANUARY);
    cal1.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
    cal1.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    cal1.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    cal1.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
    
    date.setTime(cal1.getTimeInMillis());
    
    System.out.println(date); //Sat Jan 01 00:00:00 IST 1
    
    LocalDate localDate = Instant.ofEpochMilli(date.getTime()).atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate();
    
    System.out.println(localDate); //0000-12-30
    

Expected result is 0001-01-01, but actual is 0000-12-30
Can someone explain what is the issue and how to fix this? Thanks

How would this ever become an actual thing? What is your real timezone - i.e. what does ZoneId.systemDefault(); print?

A quick summary of the duplicate target - India did not have standardised timezones until the 19th century. The java.time API knows about this fact, but the old APIs don't. Calendar thinks the midnight of 0001-01-01 occurs a little earlier than when java.time thinks it occurs, because Calendar thinks the timezone offset is at +05:30 two thousand years ago, but java.time thinks it's at the local mean time of 

probably similar reason as in the question Converting java.util.Date (01.01.0001) to java.time.LocalDate returns 29.12.0000 (different calendar systems used by the old API and by java.time)

@g00se it is IST

It’s the difference between the Julian calendar probably used by your Calendar object (you didn’t specify) for dates before 1583 and the proleptic Gregorian calendar used by LocalDate.

@Sweeper I am sorry, that is not very relevant. java.time thinks the offset for Asia/Kolkata was +05:53:28, a difference from Date of less than half an hour. The difference that the OP observes is 2 days, so the different interpretations of time zone cannot explain it. See the originals that I added and my previous comment.

An apparent difference of 2 days over a span of 2000 years. An inaccuracy of 0.0003 %. Does it matter?

@g00se it is IST That's not a real timezone. You could be in more than one country even. I suspect it's possibly Asia/Kolkata

IST may stand for Irish Summer Time, Israel Standard Time, India Standard Time (also used in Sri Lanka) and more. And most of the mentioned ones aren’t real time zones. @g00se is correct, and you may confirm or correct their suspicion of Asia/Kolkata?

As an aside, in Java don’t give year 1 as 0001. Just 1. Giving 4 diigts works in this case, but you will be surprised when 0500 gives year 320 and 0800 cannot be compiled. Numbers with a leading 0 are octal numbers.

What I said about different calendars also means that even though unexpected your observed result is correct. One quick way to check is to observe that your Date falls on a Saturday (printed Sat) and 0000-12-30 is a Saturday (check through the getDayOfWeek method). 0001-01-01 in the proleptic Gregorian calendar was a Monday so could not have been correct.

Numbers with a leading 0 are octal numbers. And why is that? Because leading zeros in a number (as opposed to a string) are meaningless. Therefore, the language inventors were able to inject a meaning for the convenience of meaning a number in a different base (8).
